# Android: Opened overflow menu is not aligned right after landscape screen rotation

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-view, android-toolbar

Basically when I open overflow menu and rotate the screen the menu becomes located at the middle of the screen (as it is at portrait screen right end).

I use usual approach to inflate menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
}
```

The only thing to note is that I hide toolbar and status bar and that's when this issue occurs. If toolbar is not hidden, it works fine.

```
activity.getSupportActionBar().hide()
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        setFooterVisible(false);
```

Comment: I believe the default implementation will destroy the overflow menu and not populate again after rotation, is this not the case?

Comment: No, it still remains open as expected, and all menu items are there, but it becomes placed in the middle of the screen in landscape.

Comment: interesting, I believe the key to understand the issue is how is it restored after rotation. I have a bug where the overflow menu is not restored, it helps for me if you can answer how it is restored

Comment: On rotation, I know that onCreateOptionsMenu dos not gets called, instead onPrepareOptionsMenu does. Invalidating menu does not change anything.  Also, I am using this library bluelinelabs/Conductor for replacing Fragments. Maybe it affects this behavior somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I noticed that menu behaves correctly if toolbar and status bar is not hidden, I just observe for menu being open/close and hide toolbar and status bar only if overflow menu is closed. Then menu is placed as expected.